# Add key:value pair if function returns non-null

Tags: javascript

I have a function that does validation for a few categories of input, let's say for example username and email.

I would like to split the validation out into separate functions for readability and I can like this:

```
function validate(username, email) {
  const errors = {};

  const usernameError = validateUsername(username);
  if (usernameError.length > 0) {
    errors.username = usernameError;
  }

  const emailError = validateEmail(email);
  if (emailError .length > 0) {
    errors.email= emailError;
  }

  return errors;
}
```

Where `validateUsername` and `validateEmail` currently return an empty string if the input is valid or a string with the error text if it is not valid.

This feels verbose, but I can't figure out how to not add the username key if `validateUsername` returns null or an empty string.

Any thoughts on how to refactor this?

Comment: The code looks pretty straightforward to me, and you only have to write this method once.

Comment: But if I have a lot of validators it would be nice to have one or two lines instead of 4 for each

Answer (score 2):

An empty String equals to `false` so you could:

```js
function validate(username, email) {
  const errors = {};

  const usernameError = validateUsername(username);
  if (usernameError) {
    errors.username = usernameError;
  }

  const emailError = validateEmail(email);
  if (emailError) {
    errors.email= emailError;
  }

  return errors;
}
```

Then you could shrink it down to something like this (but this might be unreadable to newbies):

```js
function validate(username, email) {
  const usernameError = validateUsername(username);
  const emailError = validateEmail(email);

  return {
    ...(emailError ? {emailError} : {}),
    ...(usernameError ? {usernameError} : {})
  };
}
```

I'm constructing an object in the line of the return and use the ES6 feature to construct an object using the variable name as key with their corresponding value. Before this i'm checking if the variable is `truthy`. If so, it's returning the object for destructing into the return-object. otherwise its returning an empty object for destruction which results in no addition to the return-object.

Comment: Interesting! Yeah maybe it's better to use your first suggestion since readability is still important

Answer (score 1):

> This feels verbose, but I can't figure out how to not add the username key if validateUsername returns null or an empty string.

You can take a look at [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values in javascript.
Empty string and `null` are falsy so you can do:

```js
function validate(username, email) {
  const errors = {};

  const usernameError = validateUsername(username);
  if (usernameError) {
    errors.username = usernameError;
  }

  const emailError = validateEmail(email);
  if (emailError) {
    errors.email = emailError;
  }

  return errors;
}
```

If you have more validator(s), you can look at something like adding all validators to object where key represent type and value is the validator function.

```js
const validators = {
 username: validateUsername,
 email: validateEmail,
 phone: validatePhone,
 // etc ....
};

function validate(input) {
  const errors = {};

  for(let [key, val] of Object.entries(input)) {
    const result = validators[key] ?  validators[key](val) : null;
    if (result) {
      errors[key] = result;
    }
  }

  return errors;
}

const vlauesToValidate = {
  username: 'test',
  email: 'test@test.com',
};

const result = validate(vlauesToValidate);
```

Comment: ah! I like that, I was thinking since the code looks so similar it should maybe be in a for loop, thanks for the suggestion, I wonder at what point this is better than a more easy to read and verbose version like you suggest at first

Comment: I would use the above solution for 3 or more validators. also gives more flexibility when adding more in the future...